# Speech recognition in Vue js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, dom, dom-events

I'm working with speech recognition and Vue.js

The problem is, I can't load any data, functions to the speechRecognition's method (In code it's `submitSpeech`).

My first try was to call a function in `submitSpeech` like this: `this.testFunction()`. Without succeed.

Second try was to call a function like `let function = this.testFunction()` and then call it in `recognition.onresult { function }` . The function was working, but if I wouldn't call it in `recognition.onresult { function }` , the function would be working anyway, cause of `let`. I want to call `testFunction()` when I need it.

Third try was calling function `this.testFuntion()` through the button where, but still the say problem as in situation with `let`, so still not working properly:

```
<b-button id="btnGiveCommand"
    @click="submitSpeech( this.testFunction())"
  >Tap to speak</b-button>
```

Let's say in `testFunction()` look like this:

```
testFunction{
  this.answered = !this.answered
}
```

Here is the code of `submitSpeech()`:

submitSpeech(function) {
//let function = this.testFunction()

```
  let SpeechRecognition = SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition; 
  let SpeechGrammarList = SpeechGrammarList || webkitSpeechGrammarList;

  let grammar = '#JSGF V1.0;' // Typ Gramatiky, ktorú používame

  let recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
  let speechRecognitionList = new SpeechGrammarList();
  speechRecognitionList.addFromString(grammar, 1);
  recognition.grammars = speechRecognitionList;
  recognition.lang = 'en-US';
  recognition.interimResults = false; 

  recognition.onresult = function(event) {
    let last = event.results.length - 1;
    let command = event.results[last][0].transcript;

    console.log(command)
    if(command.toLowerCase() === 'best'){ 
      //this.testFunction()
      function
    } else {
        console.log("command =/ best")
      document.querySelector('#test2').className = "123421412"
    }
  };
  recognition.onspeechend = function() {
    recognition.stop();
  };

  recognition.onerror = function(event) {
    console.log('Error occurred in recognition: ' + event.error)
  }
  recognition.start();

},
```

Does anybody have any idea how to call the function `testFunction()` in `submitSpeech(){ recognition.onresult(){ Here should the function } }`?

Thank's for any help.

Comment: Check out the event bus.  You can use that to in a disjointed way send events around in Vue. https://blog.logrocket.com/using-event-bus-in-vue-js-to-pass-data-between-components/

Comment: Thank's a lot. The Bus event is working!